# SpatiaLite Support on Windows Phone 7/8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, spatialite

Is it possible to get SpatiaLite running on either Windows Phone 7 or 8? I cant find any documentation on this and Google is failing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is looking at porting parts of [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) and use a [SpatiaLite provider](http://geobabble.wordpress.com/2009/04/11/spatialite-provider-code-for-sharpmap-09/) with it.